# Visual Studio 2015 is Injecting spaces in Mustache.js templates when formatting document

Tags: visual-studio-2015, mustache

We have several machines that all load and format HTML containing Mustache templates fine.  On one machine it is injecting spaces within the Mustache tags:

```
<input type="text" value="{{data.firstName}}">
```

becomes-

```
<input type="text" value="{{ data.firstName }}">
```

Sometimes it will even inject spaces between the quotes and the bracket.
Normally this would be no big deal other than some spaces Mustache has to trim, but sometimes I use a custom method I pass delimited data to for selecting an HTML option or translating database values to a common code key/value pair.  I may put some HTML inside a Mustache block too.  Either way the extra spaces will mess them up.

We've compared all the Text Editor/Formatting/Spacing options, but it still wants to format it with the space.  It is a .htm file, so I'd think it should use rules for HTML, JavaScript, CSS, or JSON.  We looked in C++ and C# too though just to cover bases since they use the same brackets.  It color codes the Mustache content right as well, so it knows the tag (No rule I could find for Mustache though).

Does anyone know what rule controls the format of the spaces in Mustache tags?

Comment: Are you using any plugins that may effect formatting? Visual Studio 2015 does not format my handlebars like this.

Comment: Nope.  No other plugins.  So, in an htm file when you press Ctrl K,D it doesn't alter them in VS 2015?  Are they dotted notation?  We noticed it does it more with those.  It started injecting them on every machine now, so some recent VS update must have been the cause and others didn't update yet, but did now.

Comment: I'm using VS 2015 and it doesn't do that in my HTML/JS files. Strange! Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: Same here for javascript files.  Injects space after { and before } so it won't pass jslint.  :-(

Comment: Javascript has an option under Text Editor where you can set spacing.  I have that turned off,  but it still puts the spaces in HTML files where there is no option.